# Unable to get property 'rows' of a gridview in an updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: javascript, gridview, updatepanel

I have an asp.net page with a gridview in an updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGrid" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvBatchGroups" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvBatchGroups" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="GroupID" GridLines="Both"
                     BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="gvformat" OnRowDataBound="gvBatchGroups_RowDataBound">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#95B9B9" /> 
                    <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="Double"  BorderColor="Black"/>
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupID" HeaderText="Group ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupCode" HeaderText="Group Code" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupName" HeaderText="Group Name" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupType" HeaderText="Group Type" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FinancialYear" HeaderText="Financial Year"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="IsBatchSelected" HeaderText="Batch Selected" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDetail" runat="server" Text="view" OnClick="btnDetails_Click" CausesValidation="false" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" CssClass="btn btn-comment" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                     <HeaderTemplate>Properties</HeaderTemplate> 
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:templatefield ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                     <HeaderTemplate>Select
                     <input id="cbHeaderSelect" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckAll(this)" runat="server" />
                     </HeaderTemplate>
                        <itemtemplate><asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect" runat="server"></asp:checkbox></itemtemplate>
                    </asp:templatefield>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:Button ID="bttnHidden" runat="Server" Style="display: none" />
                <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Column 8 has a checkbox that calls the following Javascript function to select all the checkboxes in the grid:

```
 function CheckAll(oCheckbox) {
     var Gridview = document.getElementById("<%=gvBatchGroups.ClientID%>");
     for (i = 1; i < Gridview.rows.length; i++) {
         Gridview.rows[i].cells[7].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked =
 oCheckbox.checked;
     } }
```

However, when I click on the Column header, the Javascript function errors displaying the following:

**Unable to get property 'rows' of undefined or null reference**

This line appears under:

```
 for (i = 1; i < Gridview.rows.length; i++)
```

Could the updatepanel be preventing the Javascript from "seeing" the gridview?

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: I'm affraid that GridRow is only in asp.net template, not in generated html, but maybe I'm wrong. Can you check your output html? For example in browser.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have viewed the source content and the gridview is not there. Do you know how the same functionality can be achieved using an updatepanel?

Comment: I recommend to use newer technology, for example asp.net mvc. It has less magic :).

Comment: That was my original plan but it was not me decision.